# Making custom tables in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to make a table in HTML & CSS like this one?

[image: https://imgur.com/3NmbYnE]

I want to have one full height column (on the right) and the rest is rows as on the image.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the [`rowspan` and `colspan` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

Comment: This is exactly it. The issue was that i had multiple <tbody> so i didnt work as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with grids:

```css
.thead {
    padding: 5px;
    grid-area: thead;
    border: 3px solid gray;
}

.col {
    grid-area: col;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.r {
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
.row-1 {
    grid-area: row-1;
}
.row-2 {
    grid-area: row-2;
}
.row-3 {
    grid-area: row-3;
}
.row-4 {
    grid-area: row-4;
}
.row-5 {
    grid-area: row-5;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "thead thead"
    "row-1 col"
    "row-2 col"
    "row-3 col"
    "row-4 col"
    "row-5 col";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="thead">thead</div>
        <div class="col">Col</div>
        <div class="r row-1">Row 1</div>
        <div class="r row-2">Row 2</div>
        <div class="r row-3">Row 3</div>
        <div class="r row-4">Row 4</div>
        <div class="r row-5">Row 5</div>
 </div>
```

[Grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) are really worth looking into.